# i want to make show//hide password but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello I want to show/hide the password but after clicking it doesn't work, the object doesn't want to hide the password, can anyone help me, where is the wrong code
[image: result]

```js
const Password = document.getElementsByClassName("teks");
const eye = document.getElementById("eye");
eye.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (Password.type === "password") {
    Password.type = "text";
    eye.classList.add("hide");
  } else {
    Password.type = "password";
    eye.classList.remove("hide");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="login-form">
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <ul class="login-list">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="cancel"></i>
    <input class="teks1" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <input class="teks" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <span class="mata">
      <i class="fa fa-eye" id="eye"></i>
    </span>
    <p><a href="">Lupa password?</a><br /></p>
    <input type="button" value="Login" class="tombol" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the eye icon, when the user enters the password to appear and when I want to see the password the eye icon works to display the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Password = document.getElementsByClassName("teks")
```

returns `array`
you need to specify it's index so your `eventlistener` can locate it. or best add `id` and use `getElementById`

```
const Password = document.getElementsByClassName("teks")[0];
```

```js
const Password = document.getElementsByClassName("teks")[0];
const eye = document.getElementById("eye");
eye.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (Password.type === "password") {
    Password.type = "text";
    eye.classList.add("hide");
  } else {
    Password.type = "password";
    eye.classList.remove("hide");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="login-form">
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <ul class="login-list">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="cancel"></i>
    <input class="teks1" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <input class="teks" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <span class="mata">
      <i class="fa fa-eye" id="eye"></i>
    </span>
    <p><a href="">Lupa password?</a><br /></p>
    <input type="button" value="Login" class="tombol" />
  </ul>
</div>
```